# Getting "Failed to lookup view in views directory" but project is well before

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, routes, runtime-error

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819445/router-use-requires-a-middleware-function-but-got-undefined][1]

so my question is still related to previous question n for now I add google login but when I click google login button then showed error like this

also yesterday my project still can running well with only google login error but today I checked my project and then I got this error even when just running project again as same as when I click on google login button

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\app.js:55:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Refia\OneDrive\Documents\skilogictest\skill_logic\Skill Test\app_auth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
```

thanks for any answers and helps